# Probability that if die is rolled seven times the maximum value is $5$; the numbers $4, 5, 6$ each appear at least once

Tags: probability, problem-solving

I need some help with the following exercise:

Roll a die $7$ times. What is the probability: 
i) that the maximum value is $5$?
ii) that the numbers $4, 5, 6$ each appear at least once?

I can't understand how to solve it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question, and tell us where you got stuck. Our aim is to improve your mathematical skills.

Answer (score 1):

Hints

i) Find the probability that the max is less than $6$ and the probability that the max is less than $5$. Be aware that the second event is a subset of the first.

In mathematical language find: $$P(M\leq5)-P(M\leq4)$$ where $M$ denotes the maximum.

ii) Find the probability of the complement and apply inclusion/exclusion.

In mathematical language find:$$P(E_4\cup E_5\cup E_6)$$ where $E_i$ denotes the event that number $i$ is not thrown.

Comment: could you help me by writing the solution ? i can't understand the english terms

Comment: See my edit with additional mathematical terms.